# Swap with precedent

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table like this (with the `num` column being indexed) :

```
+-----+--------------+
| num | lots of cols |
+-----+--------------+
|  31 | bla 31       |
|  67 | bla 67       |
|  88 | bla 88       |
|  89 | bla 89       |
+-----+--------------+
```

And I want to swap the num of one row whose num is X with the precedent one (based on the order defined by `num`).

For example if I'm given X=88, I want to update the `num` of two rows so as to get

```
+-----+--------------+
| num | lots of cols |
+-----+--------------+
|  31 | bla 31       |
|  67 | bla 88       |
|  88 | bla 67       |
|  89 | bla 89       |
+-----+--------------+
```

What would be the simplest and most efficient query or queries to do this without fetching all the columns (if possible just updating the `num` column) ?

Comment: Do you have an autoincrementing id column?

Comment: @Mihai no, I don't. The primary key is a combination of 3 columns among them the num.

Comment: edit : removing the unique constraint from the sake of this question and for the users who answered when it wasn't really clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get the number that you want to swap with:

```
select max(num)
from TheTable
where num < 88
```

Then use that to swap the numbers:

```
update TheTable
set num = (67 + 88) - num
where num in (67, 88)
```

(Note however that this only works as long as the sum of the two numbers are still within the range of the data type.)

Comment: This looks good. I forgot about this old trick... I don't think I'll get better but I wait a little before accepting just in case somebody does it in one query.

Comment: Damn. As `num` is part of my primary key, the query doesn't work.

Comment: As my initial question didn't make it clear there was a "unique" constraint, I'll remove it from the question and accept this answer.

Comment: @Laurence: 88 - -2147483648 = 2147483736, which is out of range for an int.

Comment: @Guffa I stand corrected. It will have to be `val1 ^ num ^ val2` in that case :)

Answer (score 3):

This is based on @Guffa's answer.  It simply combines the two queries into one:

```
update TheTable cross join
       (select max(num) as num
        from TheTable
        where num < 88
       ) other
    set num = (other.num + 88) - num
    where num in (other.num, 88);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
SET @swap = 88;

UPDATE tableName
SET
  num = CASE WHEN num=@swap THEN
          (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(num) FROM tableName WHERE num<@swap) s)
        ELSE @swap END
WHERE
  num <= @swap
ORDER BY
  num DESC
LIMIT 2
```